# Searching vaadin-server jar lower than 7.0

Tags: vaadin

My project is built with Vaadin 6.8.4. I need to use Vaadin server as well. However I can find vaadin server 7.0.0 but I need version 6 which I cannot find anywhere. I don't want to upgrade my project as now. Kindly, can anyone help me out here?

I tried using Vaadin server 7.0.0 with Vaadin 6.8.4 but in the module of sending file as download for client, I get this error:-
`java.lang.VerifyError: (class: com/vaadin/server/FileDownloader, method: extend signature: (Lcom/vaadin/ui/AbstractComponent;)V) Incompatible argument to function`

Answer (score 2):

In vaadin 6 there was no vaadin-server-xxxx.jar.
Everything is in the vaadin-6.8.xx.jar.

If your code is referencing com/vaadin/server, then probably you have some components which require vaadin 7.

It's not possible to mix components between 6.x and 7.x